# Flexslider With Wordpress Issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, flexslider

Using Flexslider with WordPress, the console shows no error at all but the slider is not working, I'm following the old tutorial may be the code is updated not sure.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script>
                    $(window).on('load', function() {
                        $('#slider').flexslider({
                        animation: "slide"
                    });
                    });
                </script>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<header class="header clear" role="banner">
                <div class="navcanvas">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                            <!-- logo -->
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_custom_logo();?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /logo -->

                            <!-- nav -->
                            <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
                                <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
                            </nav>
                            <!-- /nav -->
                    </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
            </div><!-- /.navcanvas -->

            <div class="slider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/920/300/" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/920/300/" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/920/300/" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <div>

</header>   <!-- /header -->
```

**Functions.php**

```
function html5blank_styles()
{

    wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!;


    wp_register_style('flexslidercss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css', array(), '2.7.1', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('flexslidercss'); //Slider css

// Load HTML5 Blank scripts (header.php)
function html5blank_header_scripts()
{
    if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin()) {
        //Jquery
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        // wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), '4.3.0'); // Conditionizr
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Enqueue it!

          wp_register_script('conditionizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js', array(), '4.3.0'); // Conditionizr
        wp_enqueue_script('conditionizr'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js', array(), '2.7.1'); // Modernizr
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('html5blankscripts'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_register_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'), '2.7.1'); // Custom scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('flexslider'); // Slider js

    }
}
```

It seems that lots of people is having this error.let me knon if any screenshot or code is needed. it seems like stackoverflow won't let me post unless i type in some details which are not necessary. please ignore this whole paragraph.

Comment: I don't see you enqueue styles and scripts using : `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function' );` !!

Comment: im using html5blank theme, its at the bottom the js is loading but not working